# What is $\epsilon_0 \cdot \omega$?

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

I'm a bit stuck on telling what the ordinal $\epsilon_0 \cdot \omega$ is.

$$\epsilon_0 = \sup \{1, \omega, \omega^{\omega}, \omega^{\omega^{\omega}}, \dots \}$$

so

$$\epsilon_0 \omega = \sup \{\omega, \omega^2, \omega^{\omega + 1}, \omega^{\omega^{\omega} + 1}, \dots \}$$

My confusion is whether or not in the limit these two sequences end up resulting in the same ordinal, i.e. is $\epsilon_0 \cdot \omega = \epsilon_0$?

Comment: The calculation is incorrect.  Ordinal multiplication is continuous on the right, but not continuous on the left.  Since $\epsilon_0=\omega^{\epsilon_0}$ then $\epsilon_0\omega=\omega^{\epsilon_0}\omega=\omega^{\epsilon_0+1}$ and this is a Cantor normal form so it's not further simplifyable in any meaningful sense.